# How to view all metadata of a .dll file with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#

When I press follow symbol into a code in .dll format, I ended up in a [metadata] file like below.

[image]

It is useful because even without full source code you can also see other fields in a particular class. But the question is I would like to know all other classes in this .dll as well. (What else is available?) I can see that it also reads a .cs file name. If possible I want to know all the files included in this .dll as well.

This .dll is currently undocumented but VSCode have intellisense for its class already hinting that there might be a way to list them all. The problem is I don't know the exact name of classes. The only way is to hope that this .dll use a good namespace practice and try to follow every symbol that pops up after typing a namespace.

Comment: Are you running this on Mac? For windows you can use [JetBrains DotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/). I know how you can do it in Visual Studio, but not VSCode.

Comment: Yes I am on a Mac.

Comment: Why not look a reflector program ? Ilspy is open source.

Comment: ILSpy has a VSCode extension.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have tried ILSpy for VSCode and most of the time it did not decompile or just nothing happen when running the command. dotPeek does not work on a mac.

The solution I found is actually **Visual Studio Community** for macOS. Create a dummy project then add DLLs to the project then an "Assembly Browser" tab will pops up if you double click them.

Works flawlessly, also with search bar.

[image]